# OpenGL: failed to create frame buffer object

Tags: c++, opengl

An OpenGL FBO is created and bind color buffer and stencil buffer to it .

```
glCheck(glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, fbo));

// Delete old framebuffers if ever created.
if ( clrRbo != 0)
    glDeleteRenderbuffers(1, & clrRbo);
if ( stencilRbo != 0)
    glDeleteRenderbuffers(1, & stencilRbo);

// Create new framebuffers with new size.
int maxSize; glGetIntegerv(GL_MAX_RENDERBUFFER_SIZE,  &maxSize);

glCheck(glGenRenderbuffers(1,&clrRbo));
glCheck(glBindRenderbuffer(GL_RENDERBUFFER,clrRbo));
glCheck(glRenderbufferStorage(GL_RENDERBUFFER, GL_RGBA, (std::min)(maxSize,m_localvp.pix_width),(std::min)(maxSize, m_localvp.pix_height)))

glCheck(glGenRenderbuffers(1,&stencilRbo));
glCheck(glBindRenderbuffer(GL_RENDERBUFFER,stencilRbo));
glCheck(glRenderbufferStorage(GL_RENDERBUFFER, GL_STENCIL_INDEX, (std::min)(maxSize,m_localvp.pix_width),(std::min)(maxSize, m_localvp.pix_height)))

// Bind new framebuffers to FBO;
glCheck(glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, fbo));
glCheck(glFramebufferRenderbuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GL_RENDERBUFFER, clrRbo));
glCheck(glFramebufferRenderbuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_STENCIL_ATTACHMENT, GL_RENDERBUFFER, stencilRbo));
```

Problem that bothers me lies at :

```
 glRenderbufferStorage(GL_RENDERBUFFER, GL_RGBA, (std::min)(maxSize,m_localvp.pix_width),(std::min)(maxSize, m_localvp.pix_height))
```

This call fails (get GL_INVALID_OPERATION error ) when different internal formats are used, which caused the failed creation of FBO. Some machine works fine with GL_RGBA and some works with GL_RGBA8, and some works with both.  What's the difference between GL_RGBA8 and GL_RGBA. How could I figure out which format is supported on current machine?

Comment: `(std::min)(maxSize,m_localvp.pix_width)` That is a very strange way to call a function.

Comment: "*How could I figure out which format is supported on current machine?*" Both are supported. The specification *does not allow* `GL_INVALID_OPERATION` to be given for formatting reasons. Indeed, the *only* way you can get that error is if the bound renderbuffer is not a valid renderbuffer object.